# Ways to associate an App Store App and a Desktop App

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am working on a product for Windows 8 that needs to perform some low-level tasks, display some UI, and communicate with an external server. I definitely need a Windows service to accomplish the low-level tasks. At the same time, I would like to use the cool features of Windows App Store apps, like push notifications, live tiles etc... for the UI. In this design, both my service and my app would communicate with my external server.

The flow would be something like: my Windows service sends some information to my server, which then sends a push notification to my App Store app.

I understand that deployment is not pretty in this scenario, but let's put that aside for now. My problem: How does the server know that the service and the app are on the same machine, and consequently linked together? i.e. When my Windows service sends information to the server, how does the server know where to send the push notification? I need is some sort of shared, unique, identifying information.

I have seen lots of discussion (usually frustrated in nature) about the lack of inter-process communication between App Store apps and desktop apps. In my case, I have two options:

1. Generate the exact same unique identifier in the service and in the app. This seems unlikely because apps don't seem to be able to access very much system-specific information. I'd love to be shown that I am wrong about this.
2. Generate a unique identifier in the server OR in the app and communicate it to the other component. Potential ways to do this:

   - Create the identifier in the app, save it to a file, and then access the file from the service.
   - Some sort of local socket solution (I've read this doesn't work, but have not tried)

Of course, option 2 seems likely to violate the Windows 8 app [Certification Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx), notably:

> Windows Store apps must not communicate with local desktop
>   applications or services via local mechanisms, including via files and
>   registry keys.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: If you have any intentions of distributing something in the Windows Store you should forget about it right now; Windows Store apps and Desktop programs live in two completely separate, isolated worlds.

Comment: Yes, it does seem that even though Microsoft is pumping Windows Store apps, they don't fit well with my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer, but if it says "via local mechanisms" then you could still possibly communicate via a cloud service as long as having both apps installed isn't necessary to have some features in the app or if you don't mean to publish the app in the store.

You could save some sort of a token in the documents folder or if your desktop app can run with appropriate permissions - it could access the local data folder of the Windows Store app to synchronize the token for use in communication with the web service.

Perhaps the user could just be asked to copy and paste a token between the two apps?

Comment: Yes, I feel like communication via the cloud is not breaking any rules. 

User copy/paste could work, as well as communication via files (though Microsoft would likely not approve my app if it figured out what I was doing.)

I also thought about writing a file-system filter driver that could act as a broker between the desktop app and the Windows Store app. 
After thinking about that for a while, using traditional Windows desktop UI seemed a lot more enticing.

Comment: Why do your apps need to communicate though? Maybe you should just do a WPF app? You're not getting much benefit it seems from having a Store app if you need a desktop one too. It won't run on RT anyway.

Comment: I agree with you. I have re-designed for desktop only. This decision was made easier when I found out that you can actually display Toast notifications form a [desktop app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2)